# Javascript - String replace by multiple strings

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I'm wondering if a function exists that does this thing:

```
var greetings = "Hello %s, I'm %s"
greeting.replace('Mickey','Minnie');

// Should return: Hello Mickey, I'm Minnie
```

**EDIT**

Thank you all for the help!

I created a little node package for it, in case anyone needed something like this:

[str-render link](https://github.com/burawi/str-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not able to use ES6 (template literals) or a polyfill, you can also pass a function to `.replace()`.

See:

```
var greeting = "Hello %s, I'm %s"
var replacements = ['Mickey', 'Minnie'];

greeting.replace(/%s/g, function() {
  return replacements.shift();
});
```

This returns **"Hello Mickey, I'm Minnie"**

Answer (score 6):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in an IIFE:

```js
const greetings = ((a, b) => `Hello ${a}, I'm ${b}`)('Mickey','Minnie');

console.log(greetings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just "traditional" Javascript:

```
var greetings = "Hello %s, I'm %s"
(['Mickey','Minnie']).forEach (function (n) { greetings = greetings.replace ('%s', n) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you all!

I created a little node package for it, in case anyone needed something like this:

[str-render link](https://github.com/burawi/str-render)